# Show by any method of construction that the language $A = \{a^i b^j\}$ is regular.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-language

Show by any method of construction that the language $A = \{a^i b^j\}$ is regular.

restrictions:

1) $i$ is a multiple of any given integer $n$

2) $j$ is a multiple of any given integer $m$

3) $n,m \geq 0$

I tried to prove this by cases. Having a case where n is even and a case where n is odd. And the same cases for m. But I didn't make it very far with this. I am not well versed in proving this type of problem and would appreciate it if someone could give a me a direction to move in. I hope the description of the problem is clear enough if not let me know.

Comment: Are you familiar with regular expressions? Finite state automata?

Comment: Yes I know all the formal definition for finite state machines and regular expressions. I'm still learning how to apply that knowledge to proofs however. Some problems seem straight forward, but this one just didn't click I suppose. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: Try this regular expression: $$(\underbrace{aa\ldots aa}_{n})^*(\underbrace{bb\ldots bb}_{m})^*$$

Comment: So you can have n a's 0 or many times followed m b's 0 or many times? Thank you that was very obvious I feel stupid. @BrianM.Scott

Comment: You’re welcome. Yes, that’s exactly right.